Trigger on pipeline and with path filter
I would like to trigger a pipeline when a stage in another pipeline has completed, but I only want to do it if there have been changes in a specific folder.
Triggering based on the source pipeline works as expected, but I don't see an option for setting path filters. If I add a normal trigger on path, it gets executed immediately if there are changes in the folder, and not when the source pipeline has completed:
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - path/to/folder/*

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: SourcePipeline
    source: SourcePipeline
    trigger:
      stages:
        - sourcestage

Is this possible to achieve in ADO? I guess an alternative is to still trigger it, but make a step or condition in the pipeline that aborts if no changes to files in the folder.

I have seen a work around that adds a job step that performs a powershell script to look for changes on your path.  Then another job step that depends on the first.

The workaround shared by @RuiJarimba should be the best choice. We can use git command(e.g. git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only) in source pipeline to check if the specific folder has been changed, then we can determine if the pipeline need to add the build tag.  In the target pipeline, we can combine tags and stages filter to set Pipeline resource trigger

Path filters are not supported in the pipeline resource.
If you are able to detect if the folder changes in the source build, consider adding a build tag when that happens - for example, HAS_CHANGES:
- task: Bash@3
    inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$HAS_CHANGES"
    displayName: 'Set build tag: HAS_CHANGES'

You can then configure the pipeline resource in the destination pipeline as follows:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: SourcePipeline
    source: SourcePipeline
    trigger:
      tags: # List of tags that when matched will trigger the pipeline. 
        - HAS_CHANGES
      stages: # List of stages that when complete will trigger the pipeline. 
        - sourcestage


Cool, looks promising. And do we only know about changed files in the source pipeline, or could it be done in the target pipeline as well?

@Jeppe if you want to detect changes in the target pipeline you'll need to use another solution/workaround.

This can't be done.
There is no option to path filter on a linked pipeline's trigger.
